# Overriding nn.Module's ".to" does not work when module is child

Tags: python, pytorch

Consider the following code :

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn


class Child(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,device):
        super().__init__()
        self.device = device
        self.param = nn.Parameter(torch.randn((3,2)))

    def forward(self,x):
        print("nothing again")
        return x
    
    def to(self,*args,**kwargs) :
        super().to(*args,**kwargs)
        print("SPECIAL")
        if("device" in kwargs) :
            self.device=kwargs["device"]

class Dad(nn.Module) :
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.child = Child('cuda')
    
    def forward(self,x):
        x=self.child(x)
        print("nothing")
        return x


daron = Dad()
daron.to('cpu')
print("Param is now : ",daron.child.param.device)
daron.child.to('cuda')
print("Param is now : ",daron.child.param.device)
```

As you can see, in the "Child" class, I override the ".to" method such that it outputs "SPECIAL", and changes its attribute "device" to the new value. Normally, when calling .to on a Module, it will recursively call it for all its children. However, for some reason, when this is done, the "special" .to is not used. Instead, the "usual" .to is used. This can be seen by running the code, which will output :

```
Param is now :  cpu
SPECIAL
Param is now :  cuda:0
```

So, why is this happening ? When calling .to directly on the child, it is correctly overriden, but not when called recursively through daron's ".to" method. And more importantly, how can I make it work as expected ?

P.S. : I know I should not have to override .to if my code is written well. Unfortunately, I am using some third party library for which some subset of "modules" do not inherit nn.Module, and so I have to do some things by hand.

Comment: I ended up re-implementing the offending "module" so that I can use .to as intended. However, I am still curious about the answer...